# Finding Dijits in a Dijit

Tags: dojo

I've got a Widget called `ImageBox`, which just does some simple parsing and image positioning inside another widget called `SlideBox`.

Sample structure of the ImageBox node structure after parsing (what I see in the console):

```
<div class="textwrapper">
    <div class="text">
         <h2>Title of Image</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample structure of a complete SlideBox:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dj/SlideBox" widgetid="SlideBox_1">
    <div data-dojo-type="dj/ImageBox" widgetId="ImageBox_1">
        <!-- It's here!! Right here!! -->
        <div class="textwrapper">
            <div class="text">
             <h2>Title of Image</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the ImageBox `postCreate` method, I'm attempting to find the height of the textwrapper div, but all attempts to query or find the widgets with any of the dijit registry methods isn't returning anything.

Note, the textwrapper and text div's are created with dojo, not in the original markup.

I can see the widget, it's there, and I can see the `.textwrapper` div I'm trying to access.  It seems there's some order stuff or some way Dojo handles widget parsing.

How can I find the widgets inside a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment on OP's answer, as requested: To access the child widgets, wait until after postCreate() so the child widgets can be added to the DOM.

The child widgets should then be accessible from the container widget's startup() method, as per the widget lifecycle - http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/understanding_widgetbase/

Answer (score 1):

You normally would use the [registry.findWidgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html#finding-all-widgets-underneath-a-dom-node) method to find widgets below a node. As mentioned in the reference guide, findWidgets will not recursively find widgets inside widgets though...

But in your case it would be sufficient to set a data-dojo-attach-point to your textwrapper div in the widget's template. Something like this could be in your ImageBox's template html file:

```html
<div class="${baseClass}">
    <div class="textwrapper" data-dojo-attach-point="textwrapper"></div>
</div>
```

You then can reference the textwrapper div inside your ImageBox widget with:

```js
postCreate: function() {
    // use this.textwrapper to access the textwrapper div, e.g. like:
    var contentBox = domGeom.getContentBox(this.textwrapper);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm not using any templates, unfortunately. It needs to be done declaratively and thus, I'm unable to use attach points. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems kinda hacky, but it works.  By adding a `dojo/ready` call in the `postCreate` of the base class, I'm able to wait until everything's done, and then query.

I had added a few log() calls to each widget's lifecycle, and I found that the ImageBox was firing last, hence anything I put in the containing `postCreate` wasn't going to see any of the widgetcentric attributes of it's children.  Adding the `ready()` call to the `postCreate()` of the containing widget reversed the order of the log calls, effectively making it wait for all dependents to be loaded before continuing.

Comment: Just curious - startup() follows postCreate() in the widget lifecycle; is there a reason for not doing this work in startup()?  According to http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/understanding_widgetbase/ "This method is designed to handle processing after any DOM fragments have been actually added to the document"

Comment: You are so right. Put as an answer, I'll accept. Thank you for pointing this out.  I just get so caught up with the "building" functions sometimes.